Why this spike in current when switching on 7805 voltage regulator (LTSpice simulation)?
I'm simulating this circuit in LTSpice (I'll try to attach the file):

There's a LM7805 voltage regulator powered by a 9V source through a switch, and its load is just a LED with a resistor. The switch turns on and then off.
I'm measuring the current indicated in red, i.e. the current going into the IN pin of the LM7805 voltage regulator.
I got the model of the 7805 from here: https://ltwiki.org/files/LargeCollection.zip
This is the graph I get for the current:

Why is there that huge current spike the moment the switch turns on? The rest of the graph is what I expected.
Is this a real effect that I should worry about, or is it just an artifact of the simulation? And in either case, how can I avoid it?
LTSpice file: https://file.io/QHUPVw9Zsmrk

Your circuit has capacitors on regulator input and output.
Any sudden switching must charge the capacitors from 0V to 9V in some very small amount of time, and if they charge  instantly in simulation, it means infinite current used to charge them.
